# Python.NET - convert Python List to .NET List (C#)

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I am importing a python list (of string) in C# using Python.NET and I can't find any example of conversion from Python.NET dynamic object to C# List (all examples out there seems to be in the opposite direction C# to Python).

I tried to cast the dynamic python.net object with `(List<string>)` and with `Enumerable.ToList<string>()` but both failed. The `as` operator returned null. The only thing that worked was to loop over it with `foreach`... but is this really the only way and the best solution ?

Here is the code:

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
   dynamic MyPythonClass = Py.Import("MyPythonClass")
   dynamic pyList = MyPythonClass.MyList;
   
   //List<string> mylist = (List<string>)pyList;               //failed
   //List<string> mylist = Enumerable.ToList<string>(pyList);  //failed
   //List<string> mylist = pyList as List<string>;             //returns null

   List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
   foreach(string item in pyList)
   {
         mylist.Add(item);                                     //Success !
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) operator

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar : just tried and it returned null (with no error), I'll update the post.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this interop or python, but this looks like MyPythonClass.List has a runtime type that isn't a List<string> or assignable to it. Stick the debugger on and see what the run time type of pyList really is

Comment: its something that implements IEnumerable<string> but not List<string>

Comment: @Dave: yes, you're correct, it is a runtime type and the debugger says "Cannot convert type 'Python.Runtime.PyObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'"... but what should I do then ?

Comment: List has a ctor that takes an IEnumerable (which we know we have cos we can foreach it) so use that `var myList = new List<string>((IEnumerable<string>)pyList)`

Comment: @Dave: I just tried and it comes up with a similar error: Unable to cast object of type 'Python.Runtime.PyObject' to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.'

Comment: ah Ok to it must only implement IEnumerable rather than IEnumerable<T> - it looks to me like this is your best option - but like I say the python interop isn't my thing really. The only other I could think to try is casting it to an string[] ?

Comment: mm actually looking at the source https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x7a3b7b993fab126a5a205be68df1c82bd87e4de081aa0f5ad36909b54f95e3d7&fullName=&project=pythonnet/pythonnet it doesn't actually implement IEnumerable, it takes advantage of little c# oddity that foreach statements use duck typing - it doesn't care about an interface just the presence of GetEnumerator and that GetEnumerator has to return something with Current and MoveNext() - so your casting is likely to never work and what you are doing is probably best

Comment: @Dave: Thanks a lot for you help, actually casting to (string[]) did the trick, it worked. So do you think it's the the safest option or should I stick with the foreach ?

Comment: Tbh I have no idea. The foreach isn't bad I don't think but if it casts as you want then that seems good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer was (shamefully) very simple, thanks to @Dave:

```
string[] mylist = (string[])pyList;

//or

List<string> mylist = ((string[])pyList).ToList<string>();
```